# Show slected values in multi selected rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

In multi selected `:selected=>@campaign.categories.pluck(:name)` not working and even not giving any error

```
<%= f.select(:category, options_for_select(Category.all.map{|u| [u.name, u.id]}, :selected => @campaign.categories.pluck(:name) ), {}, {:multiple => true,:required => true, :class => 'form-control' }) %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few issues with your code.

```
Category.all.map{|u| [u.name, u.id]}
```

is extremely inefficient way of achieving what you need, since loads the whole Category table into memory prior processing. Here, really, you would need to use pluck:

```
Category.pluck(:name, :id)
```

Next thing, is that you can not have a collection as a selected value.

You have to actually select **a value**.

```
<%= f.select(
  :category,
  options_for_select(
    Category.pluck(:name, :id),
    selected: @campaign.categories.pluck(:name).first # concrete value here, not a collection
  ),
  {},
  multiple: true,
  {:multiple => true,:required => true, :class => 'form-control'}
) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below

```
<%= f.select(:category, options_for_select(Category.all.map{|u| [u.name, u.id]}, @campaign.categories.map{|j| [j.id]} ),:multiple => true, :required => true, :class => 'form-control' ) %>
```

or

```
<%= f.select(:category, options_for_select(Category.pluck(:name, :id), @campaign.categories.pluck(:id) ), :multiple => true, :required => true, :class => 'form-control' )
```